# JQuery: How to grab what it is selected in the selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, jquery-selectors

I have a box with one select with two options.
Depending on the options i need to display a different set of checkboxes.
Depending on what the user choose on the select i will display a set of checkboxes or another.

Here i have made here an example:

http://jsbin.com/acOXisI/20/edit

How can i grab the option selected in the selector?
And subsequently how can i display or not the checkboxes fieldset?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just a note: You don't need the `for=` attribute for a label if the input is within the label :)

Comment: Thank you guys for all the replies! There was so much good replies and all working! Such a pity i had to choose only one as the correct one.
Anyway Stack Overflow rocks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript you need is:

```
// hide the fieldsets on page load
$(".otion1, .otion2").hide();



$("select").change(function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  if($this.val() === "1") {
    $(".otion1").show();
    $(".otion2").hide();
  } else if($this.val() === "2") {
    $(".otion1").hide();
    $(".otion2").show();
  } else {
    $(".otion1, .otion2").hide();
  }

});


// prevent hidden checkboxes from being submitted
$("form").submit(function() {
  $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").filter(":hidden").each(function() {
    this.checked = false;
  });
});
```

and add some values to your select options:

```
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
```

See edited demo: http://jsbin.com/acOXisI/23/edit

Comment: Also note that you spelled 'option' as 'otion' - could lead to some typos/errors...

Comment: Thank to point out that and thanks for the answer. It was exactly what i needed!

Comment: Good solution but note that the hidden values will still be submitted.

Comment: Good point. JS addition at http://jsbin.com/acOXisI/23/edit solves this. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
jQuery("#selector option:selected").val();
```

Or to get the text of the option, use `text()`:

```
jQuery("#selector option:selected").text();
```

**More Info:**

- http://api.jquery.com/val/
- http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 1):

First off, you shouldn't have duplicate ids on the page.

Also, I'd suggest you put unique input names for all the checkboxes and always submit all of them from a single form (and you'd ignore those you don't need). The functionality you want can be achieved in many ways, one of them being hiding both fieldsets and setting a listener to the select element - you can use the onchange event, and check which one is selected and according to that show the appropriate fieldset.

When you check the submitted data, first check the select value, and then only the appropriate checkboxes.

Comment: You was right. there was confusion with ids. I have changed them and edit the question. Should be better now.

Comment: Great then, glad I could help without giving you a single line of code. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use jQuery:

```
$().ready(function(){
  $('#selector').change(function(){
    value=$(this).find(":selected").text();
    console.log(value)
    if (value == 'Option 1'){
       $('.otion1').show()
       $('.otion2').hide()
    }
    else{
       $('.otion1').hide()
       $('.otion2').show()
    }
  })
})
```

There is your bin cloned and working:

http://jsbin.com/UcaWUCA/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with jQuery. Note that hidden fields will still get submitted so they need disabling too:

```
$(function(){
  $("#selector").on("change", function(){
      $(".otion1, .otion2").hide().find("input").attr("disabled","disabled");
      $("."+$(this).val()).show().find("input").removeAttr("disabled");
  });
  $("#selector").trigger("change");//run on load      
});
```

http://jsbin.com/aVihIJOr/1/edit

Comment: Is a very good point yours. I think i will not need, because i don't need to submit the form. I need to display that box in a Google Map. There will be different options/paths and the checkboxes/groups will correspond to different groups of markers to display. So think i do not have to worry about submitting values, right? Anyway thank you to point out that!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use $("#selector").val() to get the selected option.

```
$("#selector").change(function(){

 option = $(this).val();

 if(option == 1){

   $(".option1").show();
   $(".option2").hide();

 } else if(option == 2) {

  $(".option2").show();
  $(".option1").hide();

 } else {

  $(".option2").hide();
  $(".option1").hide();

 }

});
```

Working example:
http://jsbin.com/acOXisI/10/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

I have added unique Div Ids to your options sets and then have linked them with the exact selected value.

Example:
http://jsbin.com/acOXisI/18/edit

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#selector').change(function(){
    value=$(this).find(":selected").val();
    if (value == 'option1'){
       $('#option1').show();
       $('#option2').hide();
    }
    else if(value == 'option2'){
      $('#option1').hide();
       $('#option2').show();
    }else{
      $('#option1').show();
       $('#option2').show();
    }
  });
});
```